# Picasso centerCrop and fit get different results

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I want to insert an image to an ImageView, which gets used as a background. This background is in a RecyclerView. When it gets loaded the first time, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I scroll to another item and scroll back, it looks like this (it should always look like this):

[image]

Here i add the image:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(StoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.cardView.setMinimumHeight(height/3);
    holder.layout.setMinimumHeight((int) ((float) width / 4));
    //set image

    Picasso.with(activity).load(MainPostAdapter.URL + 140 + ".png").
            transform(new BlurTransform(holder.background.getContext())).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.background);
    holder.background.setAlpha(0.25f);
}
```

And this is the image itself:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/story_view_background"/>
```

What could the problem be?

EDIT:
whole XML (It doesn't show all of the code. Here is also pastebin:http://pastebin.com/8rJvSx7V):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/story_view_background"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/story_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50px">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/story_view_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/story_view_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/story_view_image"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: show more XMLs, there might be the problem. your `ImageView` probably should have different width and height set

Comment: @snachmsm I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `android:layout_height="150dp"` for your `CardView` (don't use px!). Its child `FrameLayout` is unnecesarry (`CardView` is extending `FrameLayout` and have set same attributes set), remove it.

It's not so well written, all your `View`s have `match_parent` set for height, besides Image and Text views... Your item is probably trying to fit `RecyclerView` height in this case ("whole screen") and is measured without image at first time (Picasso async downloading, setting image when view is already measured). But when you inflate your `View` again (scroll and recycle) new list item will be measured differently, because Picasso will insert your image "in runtime", no need to async fetching (cache)